# migrate a class from v1 to v2 in scala3

Tags: java, scala, design-patterns

I am new to scala (10 years of java). I am asking a coding design question related to migrating data class(es).

We have a service that mostly just pass through data from producer to consumers, the main data class is `Foo`, now the business requirements have changed, the spec of this data class becomes `Bar`, both from the consumer and to the producers.

`Foo` and `Bar` shares some fields, e.g. ids, but many other fields are different.

Example:

```java
final case class Foo(
id1: String, 
id2: String, 
...
fooOnlyField1: ???, 
fooOnlyField2: ???, 
)

final case class Bar(
id1: String, // same as foo's id1
id2: String, // same as foo's id2
...
barOnlyField1: ???, 
barOnlyField2: ???, 
)
```

Most of the orchestration logic remain unchanged, I want to create a "superclass" `Baz` for `Foo` and `Bar`, and change the all method parameters from `Foo` to `Baz`, and do pattern match only at a few places necessary.

I can think of 2 ways of doing this:

**option 1**

Make `Baz` the trait with common fields, and make `Foo` and `Bar` extends `Baz`.

```java
sealed trait Baz: 
  def id1: String 
  def id2: String
case class Foo extends Baz: ??? 
case class Bar extends Baz: ???
```

**option 2**
Make `Baz` a union type or opaque union type, provide a fold method to get all common fields:

```java
opaque type Baz = Foo | Bar 
object Baz: 
  def fromBar(v: Bar) = v
  def fromFoo(v: Foo) = v
  def fold[T](v: Baz, f1: Foo => T, f2 => T):T = v match {
    case foo: Foo => f1(foo)
    case bar: Bar => f2(bar) 
  } 
  def id1(v: Baz) = fold(v, _.id1, _.id2)
```

I am leaning toward the option 2, for the following reasons:

1. if we migrate to `qux` in the future, the common fields may no longer be common among them.
2. this doesn't need to change any `Foo` class code, even though we have control there.
3. option 2 doesn't use inheritance, so i think it's more functional?

option 1 potentially has less code change since all the `foo.id1` calls doesn't need to change.

I know this maybe a subjective topic, but wondering if SO scala community has known conventions to do this type of migrations. Appreciate any input, Thanks!

Comment: Option 2 does feel kind of elegant, although you could do the same with option 1, just don't add any common fields if you are worried about that.

Comment: Keep It Simple Stupid.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, true you can do it in option 1 without any common fields, good point. The reason i like option 2 is because it’s impossible to add common field that might be deprecated i the future. Option 2 feels more elegant to me too, all fields are declared in the same class instead of spread in a hierarchy.

Comment: @GaëlJ thanks for commenting, which one feels more KISS to you?

Comment: Not really impossible, since you could add those as extension methods on `Baz`. I do agree people may find that more cumbersome than worth it compared to the inheritance case, but I don't think that is a good enough argument. Having the trait without any common fields, and a comment saying not to add them would be more than enough for me.

Comment: option3: Add a typeclass `trait HasID[T]{ def id1(v: T); def id2(v: T)}`, and implement it for Foo and Bar, e.g. `object HasID { given HasID[Foo] = HasID[Foo] with { def id1(v: Foo): .. }}`

Comment: Option 4 (possible in some cases): keep them separated and just convert from the one containing more information into the one containing less information where necessary.